# The deleted view keeps on loading in my iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I had a view called HomeViewController.xib which I deleted. Now, for some reason that view is still being loaded when the application starts. How can I set a different view to be displayed when the application starts?

Answer (score 0):

The Nib/Xib file that loads when the application is launched is specified in the Info.plist file, in the NSMainNibFile attribute.

Comment: I cannot edit that file! I think my whole project is messed up! I will create a new project and copy the files there!